# Dynamic Filtering at PowerBI Report level

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a report with 4 visualizations and a few cards that is currently displaying all of the data. I'd like to filter the data (and thus the visualizations) using some logic that uses the slicer value.

I have a planning table with lots of dates but here's a sample:

```
FiscalYear | ReportDate  |  Status   | 
2017       | 01/4/2018   | Open      | 
2018       |             | Open      | 
2017       |             | Closed    |
2016       | 01/10/2016  | Complete  | 
2016       | 01/8/2017   | Complete  |
```

The slicer values are years, which are fed into some logic to effectively define a new table (or flag the existing table), e.g.

Slicer Value = 2017
Include anything reported on in 2017 or still open:

```
FiscalYear | ReportDate  |  Status   | 
2017       |             | Closed    |
2016       | 01/8/2017   | Complete  |
```

Slicer Value = 2018
Include anything reported on in 2018 or still open:

```
FiscalYear | ReportDate  |  Status   | 
2017       | 01/4/2018   | Open      | 
2018       |             | Open      |
```

The logic isn't really important, beyond knowing that some records could pop up in both years. I'm just wondering what is the best strategy for doing this?

I could filter the data by my logic in each measure but this is very clunky. And I can't use a calculated column as it's only done once and I said, some data will span multiple years..

I also have a date table with every date from 2003 to 2035..

Thanks

Comment: Why is only one of the 2016 rows included? Is the second one closed? How can we tell? I'm guessing there should be some kind of ID column.

Comment: Hi. Because the other 2016 row was reported on in that financial year (i.e. 2016/17). The logic isn't so important, it's more the filtering 'strategy'. I can add an ID column but then do I have to filter each measure and/or visualisation by that? Or is there a report level filter? thanks

Comment: By the way, I've noticed that you haven't accepted any answers to any questions you have asked. I'd encourage you to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).